# Have solr only return facets where applicable to higher order search term

Tags: solr

Data:

> ```
> PetType   LivesIn Name
> Fish  Lake    Tom
> Fish  Fishbowl    Dick
> Fish  Aquarium    Harry
> Dog   Farm    Fido
> Dog   House   Fluffy
> Dog   Wild    Duke
> ```

I would like to search on PetType=Fish and only get back the LivesIn facets values Lake,Fishbowl, Aquarium. It seems by default, that the Dog's LivesIn facet values of Farm, House, Wild are returned with zero counts. BTW: Per the docs, I was told to do an fq for Fish so the results use the cache.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Solr to remove faceted field when it doesn't have any data](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11897189/solr-to-remove-faceted-field-when-it-doesnt-have-any-data)

Comment: This is already answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11897189/solr-to-remove-faceted-field-when-it-doesnt-have-any-data

Comment: I do not want the facets removed where count < 1. For example: if I search on the Name "arry", I would like to still get the Lake, Fishbowl, Aquarium facets even with zero count (Noting that I did need to specify Fish in query). That was what I was trying to express by saying "higher order search term".e.g. Fish.

Comment: That's not possible with pur SOLR. You have to add some logic based on the the PetType to define the facets and the zero count behavoir

Comment: So if it is not possible via a query. I guess I would have to create a WaterType facet for Fish and a LandType facet for Dog. Like if you had Books and Jeans you would have YearPublished and Size respectively. Is that correct?

Comment: That's one solutions. The other is to specify the facets and the zero cound behavoir per query depnding on the PetType in your application.

Comment: I don't understand how "specify the facets and zero count per query" would work to filter to just PetType.Fish. Can I specify facet values in a query, I thought you could only specify the facets(e.g. LivesIn)